# Parse out Wikipedia markup from files in a directory

Tags: java, parsing, wikipedia

I used lucene's ExtractWikipedia tool to extract a bz2 dump of the latest english wiki pages. The resulting .txt files still have the wikipedia markup language in them. Is there a tool or python script that I can run over the directory to only parse out the content from each file in the directory? (ie: modify the files so that they only contain content, no markup)

Alternatively, is there a java library or package which can accomplish this? I'm hoping to integrate it into the Lucene class, ExtractWikipedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this a wikiprep it's a ready perl script that (you will need to install perl first  )

- removes the wikimarkup language
- generate heirarchial categories
- removes redirections
- generates an XML format that's easily to parse

http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~gabr/resources/code/wikiprep/

it may take some couple of hours to run over all wikipedia dumb
and may need a large memory about 6GB ram